# Why does datetimepicker corrupt the year value if minutes/seconds/milliseconds are '0'

Tags: knockout.js, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm using the [Bootstrap datatimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) in a Knockout.js viewmodel.  Here is the setup:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.dateTimePicker = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        //initialize datepicker with some optional options
        var options = allBindingsAccessor().dateTimePickerOptions || {};
        options['format'] = options['format'] || "dddd, Do MMMM YYYY, HH:mm"; //default format
        options.ignoreReadonly = true;
        options.defaultDate = valueAccessor()();
        $(element).datetimepicker(options);

        //when a user changes the date, update the view model
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "dp.change", function (event) {
            ignoreReadonly: true;
            var value = valueAccessor();
            if (ko.isObservable(value)) {
                if (event.date !== null && !(event.date instanceof Date)) {
                    value(event.date.toDate());
                } else {
                    value(event.date);
                }
            }
        });

        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
            var picker = $(element).data("DateTimePicker");
            if (picker) {
                picker.destroy();
            }
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var picker = $(element).data("DateTimePicker");
        //when the view model is updated, update the widget
        if (picker) {
            var koDate = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

            //in case return from server datetime i am get in this form for example /Date(93989393)/ then fomat this
            koDate = (typeof (koDate) !== 'object') ? new Date(parseFloat(koDate.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''))) : koDate;

            picker.date(koDate);
        }
    }
};
```

If the datetimepicker reads a datetime value in which either the **minutes**, or the **seconds** or the **milliseconds** is '0' then it does something strange to the year value.

Here is an example.  In this case both the seconds and the milliseconds are '0':

1. the database value is: 2018-06-23 12:49:**00.0000000**;
2. the ***initial*** Json viewmodel value is: 2018-06-23T12:49:00;
3. the viewmodel value ***after*** my datetimepicker has 'initialised'
   the value (notice the strange year value of '2609'): Sun Jul 02
   **2609** 01:38:44 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time); and
4. the control is rendered like this:

[image]

The same behaviour occurs if any or all of the minutes, the seconds or the milliseconds is '0'.

In contrast, for example, 2018-06-23 14:08:**05.9288927** will not exhibit this behaviour:

[image]

The code I have for 'initialising' or reading the value for the datetimepicker is doing something strange.  But I have not been able to fix it.  Can anyone help?

Comment: this.dateObservable = ko.observable(new Date(json.date.value))

In your viewModel try initializing the json value as a new Date object instead of just a string.

Comment: Hi @Budhead2004, I get a 'json is not defined error'.  Can I check exactly where I should initializing the json value?

Comment: that was just an example. You would replace the json.date.value with your variable that has the json and path to date.